# How best to redirect root to subdirectory?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

We are hosting two .NET applications on an elastic beanstalk Windows instance. How can I redirect the root domain to one of the applications? e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) should always redirect to [www.example.com/start](http://www.example.com/start)? We are using a JSON deployment manifest and some ebextensions, but I can't find an example of this kind of setup.

Comment: If you can incorporate an application load balancer as part of your elastic beanstalk setup, you might be able to use host-based routing: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: Use Url rewrite to redirect request to new url. Please learn how to use url rewrite from this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like @Norman's suggestion is exactly what I needed.